# How to upgrade rails app from 2.3.5 to 2.3.9

Tags: ruby-on-rails

At the top of environment.rb I could change from 2.3.5 to 2.3.9. Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.3.9 is a "bridge" to Rails 3. After installing the Rails 2.3.9 gem and updating your environment.rb, run your application to see if you get any deprecation warnings. If you fix those, you'll be readier for Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

no, you just avoid warning after upgrading